# Deep Learning : The validation set and test set are the same, but the results are quite different

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

During the training process, I added a validation mode and **used PSNR as an evaluation metric** (**not loss function**). The validation stage **saves the current model parameters** with the largest psnr. However, in the **testing phase**, I load the model parameters and **use the same data as the validation set as the test set**, however, the psnr of the test is **quite different** from the psnr of the validation.
And, the network model is the Unet without BN and Dropout

**Train Code simply as follows**

```py
# pytorch framework
msxpsnr = 0
for epoch in range(epochs):
     model.train()
     for idx, data in enumerate(trainDataLoader):
          optimizer.zero_grad()
          out = model(data[1])
          loss = criterion(out, data[1])
          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()
     model.val()
     for idx, data in enumerate(testDataLoader):
          out = model(data[1])
          psnr = compare_psnr(data[0], data[1])
     if psnr > maxpsnr :
          torch.save(model.state_dict())
          msxpsnr = psnr
```

Simple Example:

```
Training Phase Information:

---Validation----Epoch : 1904 ,  CurrentMaxPSNR : 27.923486654016344 , SSIM : 0.7779479678648872

Test Phase : I load the model1904.pth, result...
---Test------PSNR : 27.479514001762144 , ---------SSIM : 0.7835264324520744
```

As a novice, I really hope to get relevant guidance

Comment: Neural networks are of stochastic nature meaning that performance varies. For instance, when training you begin with a random weight initialisation, which inherently impacts the model's performance (different initialisations will yield different performances). If you test the model twice with the same data you should see near equal (if not equal) performances. The only difference will be between the training and testing.

Comment: can you post code both for psnr and what criterion is? Also, keep in mind during training the model is learning continuously while during evaluation weights are static (after the last training batch), so they will be different.

Comment: I have solved the problem, my mistake was that I used the patch in the validation phase to validate instead of the entire test image, and the data set production process was not consistent with the testing process.